# What is wrong with the syntax of this ALTER SQL statement in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this SQL ALTER statement in sqlite3 to add a unique constraint among 2 columns on an existing table.

```
ALTER TABLE tabA (info_id INTEGER, date_period NUMERIC, UNIQUE(info_id, date_period) ON CONFLICT IGNORE);
```

I get a syntax error;

```
near "(": syntax error: ALTER TABLE
```

What is wrong with the syntax?

Comment: It isn't possible to add a unique constraint to a table in SQLite which already exists.  You have to recreate the table and add the constraint in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html